# Apache: Restrict access to specific source IP inside virtual host

Tags: apache, apache2

I have several named virtual hosts on the same apache server, for one of the virtual host I need to ensure only a specific set of IP addresses are allowed to access.

Please suggest the best way to do this. I have looked at mod_authz_hosts module but it does not look like I can do it inside virtual host.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The `mod_authz_host` directives need to be inside a `<Location>` or `<Directory>` block but I've used the former within `<VirtualHost>` like so for Apache 2.2:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    <Location />
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Location>

    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/262981/how-to-install-mod-authz-host-in-apache

Comment: <Location /> is not <Location>??

Comment: @ProtectchildrenofDonbas2014 -- Fixed! I'm surprised this wasn't noticed for 9 years

Comment: @NeilC.Obremski - I want to allow 70 IPs. Is there way to define all 70+ IPs in "Allow from" attribute ?

Comment: @NeilC.Obremski Are you sure that the original `<Location />` wasn't correct? While it looks like an incorrect self-closing xml-tag, it's not xml and the slash is the value for a required argument (the url)

Answer (score 63):

For Apache 2.4, you would use the [Require IP directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html#reqip). So to only allow machines from the 192.168.0.0/24 network (range 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.0.255)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Location />
      Require ip 192.168.0.0/24
    </Location>
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

And if you just want the localhost machine to have access, then there's a special [Require local directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_authz_host.html#reqlocal).

> The local provider allows access to the server if any of the following conditions is true:
>
> - the client address matches 127.0.0.0/8
> - the client address is ::1
> - both the client and the server address of the connection are the same
>
> This allows a convenient way to match connections that originate from the local host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Location />
      Require local
    </Location>
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Require local should be the answer, as it enables you to get your machine at all three of the following hosts: `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, and `ServerAlias` set in your vhost (plus ipv6 if enabled).

Comment: @pydoge thanks! yeah it is really useful for only **one** specific IP address (localhost), but the OP technically is asking for "a specific *set of IP addresses*". And you're right, a lot of people (myself included), found this page while searching for how to restrict it to just localhost - like you point out

Comment: Doesn't work! Running in a docker container may be the problem. I plan to use a reverse proxy and need to block off direct access, and I just cannot get this to work.

Comment: @JeffPuckett - I want to allow 70 IPs. Is there way to define all 70+ IPs in "Require ip" attribute

Comment: I have multiple virhosts, running apache 2.4 "Require ip" inside Location or Directory isn't working, tried everything, followed every guide I could find

Comment: I guess my problem is that apache only sees docker ip's and no client ip's since I am running apache as a docker container. See also https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/14705/how-can-i-get-client-ip-on-apache-insted-of-docker-container-ip

Answer (score 10):

If you are using apache 2.2 inside your virtual host you should add following directive ([mod_authz_host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html)):

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 10.0.0.1
```

You can even specify a subnet

```
Allow from 10.0.0
```

Apache 2.4 looks like a little different as configuration. 
Maybe better you specify which version of apache are you using.

Comment: Thank you for the information I was able to configure this by adding the directives inside location tags within virtual hosts

Comment: @frameworksnow well, if my answer is useful and you don't think this is the right answer, at least vote up ;)

Comment: I tried but I don't have the privilege to vote it up as per SO. I hope I get more reputation in SO soon and will come back and vote up. Thank you again for providing the input.

Comment: The subnet can also be specified as `Allow from 192.168.1.0/24`, which is way more idiomatic and flexible, IMO.

Answer (score 9):

In Apache 2.4, the authorization configuration syntax has changed, and the `Order`, `Deny` or `Allow` directives should no longer be used.

The new way to do this would be:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    <Location />
        Require ip 192.168.1.0
    </Location>
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Further examples using the new syntax can be found in the Apache documentation: [Upgrading to 2.4 from 2.2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html)